# SemanticUI example from Codepen does not work

Tags: javascript, html

https://codepen.io/redshift7/pen/VaKmjq

```
    $('.ui.sidebar').sidebar({
    context: $('.bottom.segment')
  })
  .sidebar('attach events', '.menu .item');
```

I am trying to replicate this example from codepen - I am working with ejs in my project, and I want to make the sidebar pop out from the left. However, when I put my header.ejslike the pastebin (https://pastebin.com/c9ijEjDq), I get the look, that I am aiming for, then I attach the JS in a script tag in the footer.ejs and it does not work ... there is simply no change etc. 
(I know I should not add a script in HTML; just for testing purposes ....)

I hope someone can help me with that ...

Comment: The pastebin seems incomplete.

Comment: The pastebin only contains my header.ejs.
the <div class="pusher" is closed in the footer.
And my page content is in several files... 
index.ejs for the main page, new.ejs for the form to create a new object 
Maybe SemanticUI does not work right with split files like ejs partials (haven't tried tbh)

Comment: I see two <body>
<body>
tags in your pastebin

Comment: header.ejs: https://pastebin.com/hqQuWWgJ
footer.ejs: https://pastebin.com/UvhJL47W

---

did a check: I was missing a </div> but nothing changed ....
I fear I am doing something entirely wrong, such as connecting the script at the wrong place ... :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the complete pastebins. Tested this and realised your header was wrongly putting jquery in a stylesheet tag. Should be in a script tag

```
<head>
    <title>DemoExhibits</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

This is the result with that change

[image: result]

Comment: cheeeeez ... I had not seen that :-D that's slightly sad ... 

Now I got the Sidebar working, but my index.ejs (which the partials header & footer embrace) is not being displayed ... I'll figure that one out tomorrow ...

Comment: Great. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct here.